# How to show other custom attribute instead of name customer in top link magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer, toplinks, name

In my case, i have two type of customer: for local customer i will keep the firstname lastname in top link if it's connected else i want to display a custom attribute that i added in registration form so i will have instead this information and then the dropdown in top link so how to proceed  please any help ?
[image]

Comment: overwrite the template

Comment: waht template please

Comment: check my update question please

Answer (score 1):

**Please try below code**

```
<? 
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $customerRepositoryInterface = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface');
    $customerSession = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
    if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
        $customerId = $customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
        $customeratt = $customerRepositoryInterface->getById($customerId);
        $customAttributeCode = 'custom_name';
        echo $cattrValue = $customeratt->getCustomAttribute($customAttributeCode); //Please echo this line when you want display custom name.
    }
?>
```

Comment: thanks for your replay just one question where to put this code

Comment: **Override this file into your theme and put in respective  <li> tag**
 
`vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/account/customer.phtml`

Comment: i tried this and i get a white page with just icon of language and the label skip menu

Answer (score 0):

Turn on debug hint mode in BO and override in theme